# How to do click on element with Javascript in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I want to do click on an element that it seems to be invisible to normal commands of Selenium driver and Selenium IDE.

Using Selenium Chromedriver with Python this command doesn't work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='abc.def(123,456789);']")
```

I need to use javascript to simulate the user click and it works in this way:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='abc.def(123,456789);']"))
```

So, I'd like to know how can I use javascript to simulate the user click on Selenium IDE?.  I've tried like this but is not working.

```
Command: execute script
Target: arguments[0].click();
Value: xpath=//a[@onclick='abc.def(123,456789);']
```

I hope make sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='abc.def(123,456789);']").click();
```

Selenium always uses javascript.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I tested your suggestion like this: `Command: execute script` and in `Target` the code you suggested but I get this error `Failed:
driver is not defined`

Comment: you need to instantiate your webdriver... Webdriver driver = new Chromedriver();  May need to set path too...

Comment: I may be confusing you.  I don't use Selenium IDE... but that looks to be a way to record and playback... like the old-school Selenium browser plugins.  Maybe what you need is to move to using the newer versions of Selenium?

Comment: But how to instantiate webdriver on `Selenium IDE`? I'm not working with Selenium Chromedriver, but with Selenium IDE

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium IDE.... so forgive me.  I've confused Selenium with Selenium IDE here.

Comment: No issue. Thanks for your help. Maybe some other person could help me.

Comment: it's possible that driver is assumed in the IDE... try find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='abc.def(123,456789);']").click();